# Some of the action buttons does not work after bootsrap

Tags: jsf

I have a project and I decided to make it look better. I learned how to use bootstrap and then tried on some of my pages. Although doing the same things on **xhtml** pages, some of my pages' buttons does not work correctly. Here is an example from my code

my add function which is being used from interface:

```
@Override
public void add(Object object) {

    Session session = factory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(object);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();

}
```

and i use it like this in my registerpage:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                template="/template/site.xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">



    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form> 
            <style>
                .error{color:red}  
            </style>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Product name</label>
                <h:inputText class="form-control" value="#{product_bean.p_name}" 
                             id="name"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="Product name can't be empty!"
                             >
                    <f:validator validatorId="only_letter_validator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="name" styleClass="error"/> <br></br>
            </div>


            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{products_controller.add(product_bean)}">
                <f:actionListener binding="#{products_controller.setFactory()}"/>
            </h:commandButton>

        </h:form>


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

my command button is working fine.
here is my delete method:

```
@Override
public void delete(int id) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.createQuery("delete from Product where id=" + id).executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

and this is how I use it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"   
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      template="/template/site.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
            <h2><h:outputText value ="Product List"></h:outputText></h2>

            <h:dataTable styleClass="table table-striped" value = "#{products_controller.productsList}" rows="#{products_controller.productsList.size()}" var = "item" border="1" headerClass="tableHeader" > 

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"> ProductID  </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_id}" />
                </h:column>


                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"> Productname </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_name}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"> Product class </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_class}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" > Productprice </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_price}"  />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"> ProductPP </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_property}" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"> ProductTotal </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p_total}" />
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>  
            <br></br><br></br>

            <div>
            Ürün ID Numarası <h:inputText value="#{deleteID}"
                                              id="id"
                                              required="true"
                                              requiredMessage="Can not be empty!"
                                              validator="#{inputValidators.OnlyLetter}"/>
            <h:message for="id" styleClass="error"/> 
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{products_controller.delete(deleteID)}">
                <f:actionListener binding="#{products_controller.setFactory()}"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

actually I am thinking they are same and it was working before I started to use bootstrap. one is working but other is not. what is different or what should I change? **I traced it** but could not figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and saw there are many people strugling with this problem. so i am sharing.

if your commandButtons are not in a <h:form> BUTTONHERE <h:form> they don't work. You can take whole table or just buttons between form parts, they will work.